# R - Subsetting list by paramaters of nested list

Tags: r, list, dplyr, plyr

I have a list `list_tot` that has nested lists.

I want to subset or create a new list that selects specific subsets based on the parameters specified, details follow:

```
List_1 <- list(a = matrix(5,2), b = matrix(5,7), c = matrix(5,9), d = matrix(5,3))
List_2 <- list(a = matrix(7,3), b = matrix(7,7), c = matrix(7,1), d = matrix(7,9))
List_3 <- list(a = matrix(5,2), b = matrix(5,7), c = matrix(5,9), d = matrix(5,3))
List_4 <- list(a = matrix(5,2), b = matrix(5,7), c = matrix(5,9), d = matrix(5,3))
List_5 <- list(a = matrix(5,2), b = matrix(5,7), c = matrix(5,9), d = matrix(5,3))

List_tot <- list(List_1, List_2, List_3, List_4, List_5)
```

that reads:

```
[[1]]

[[1]]$a
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5

[[1]]$b
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5
[3,]    5
[4,]    5
[5,]    5
[6,]    5
[7,]    5

[[1]]$c
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]    5
 [3,]    5
 [4,]    5
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    5
 [7,]    5
 [8,]    5
 [9,]    5

[[1]]$d
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5
[3,]    5


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]    7
[3,]    7

[[2]]$b
     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]    7
[3,]    7
[4,]    7
[5,]    7
[6,]    7
[7,]    7

[[2]]$c
     [,1]
[1,]    7
...etc
```

I want to select:

1. for each nested list only select list/matrix a, c, and d.
2. for each nested list select two lists/matrices with the top number of rows.

So `New_List_tot` would have an output of:

that reads:

```
[[1]]

[[1]]$c
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]    5
 [3,]    5
 [4,]    5
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    5
 [7,]    5
 [8,]    5
 [9,]    5

[[1]]$d
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5
[3,]    5
etc...
```

Any assistance would be helpful. All my attempts, attempts using plyer and dplyr, but with no success and very much stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `base R` to do this.  No packages are needed

```
lapply(List_tot, `[`, c("a", "c", "d"))
```

or with anonymous function

```
lapply(List_tot, function(x) x[c("a", "c", "d")])
```

---

if we need the top 2, `order` the number of rows (`lengths` work as these are single column `matrix`, so the number of rows are equal to the total number of elements, get the `head` of the `names` of the ordered vector of number of rows and use that to extract the inner list element

```
lapply(List_tot, function(x) {
      x1 <- x[c("a", "c", "d")]
      v1 <- lengths(x1)
      x1[head(names(v1)[order(-v1)], 2)]
    })
```

Comment: If these are not single column, would `nrow()` work?

Comment: @jackkelly Then, we need a second loop with `sapply/lapply` i.e. `v1 <- sapply(x1, nrow)`

Answer (score 2):

In base R you could do:

```
lapply(List_tot, 
   function(x) (y<-x[c("a", "c", "d")])[order(sapply(y, nrow), decreasing  = TRUE)[1:2]])

[[1]]
[[1]]$c
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]    5
 [3,]    5
 [4,]    5
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    5
 [7,]    5
 [8,]    5
 [9,]    5

[[1]]$d
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5
[3,]    5
 etc
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update

For the second goal, you can try

```
lapply(
  List_tot,
  function(lst) {
    head(lst[c("a", "c", "d")][order(-sapply(lst[c("a", "c", "d")], nrow))], 2)
  }
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$c
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]    5
 [3,]    5
 [4,]    5
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    5
 [7,]    5
 [8,]    5
 [9,]    5

[[1]]$d
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5
[3,]    5


[[2]]
[[2]]$d
      [,1]
 [1,]    7
 [2,]    7
 [3,]    7
 [4,]    7
 [5,]    7
 [6,]    7
 [7,]    7
 [8,]    7
 [9,]    7

[[2]]$a
     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]    7
[3,]    7


[[3]]
[[3]]$c
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]    5
 [3,]    5
 [4,]    5
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    5
 [7,]    5
 [8,]    5
 [9,]    5

[[3]]$d
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5
[3,]    5


[[4]]
[[4]]$c
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]    5
 [3,]    5
 [4,]    5
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    5
 [7,]    5
 [8,]    5
 [9,]    5

[[4]]$d
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5
[3,]    5


[[5]]
[[5]]$c
      [,1]
 [1,]    5
 [2,]    5
 [3,]    5
 [4,]    5
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    5
 [7,]    5
 [8,]    5
 [9,]    5

[[5]]$d
     [,1]
[1,]    5
[2,]    5
[3,]    5
```

---

- For your first goal "for each nested list only select list/matrix a, c, and d."

```
lapply(List_tot, `[`, c("a", "c", "d"))
```

- For your second goal "for each nested list select the lists/matrices with the top number of rows."

```
Map(`[`, List_tot, max.col(t(sapply(List_tot, lengths))))
```

Comment: @akrun Thanks for your feedback, can you explain a bit?

Comment: What I meant is that (may be I am wrong).  Does this have to do be done only on the selected list elements i.e. 'a', 'c', 'd' and return theone with the max number of rows for each outer lis

Comment: @akrun Okey, I see your point. I thought that these are two separate goals...

Comment: Thanks for the info, for the second goal, I am trying to get the top 2 lists with the highest number of rows. I just edited the OP.

Answer (score 2):

@akrun has a clean answer for step 1, filtering by columns. For step 2, filtering by number of rows you can try

```
library(magrittr)
List_colfilter <- lapply(List_tot, function(i)i[c("a","c","d")])

longestlist <- function(l){
  maxr <- lapply(l,nrow) %>% unlist %>% max
  l2 <- lapply(l, function(x) if(nrow(x)==maxr) x else NA)
  for (n in names(l)){
    if (is.na(l2[n])){
      l2[n] <- NULL
    }
  }
  return(l2)
}
List_longfilter <- lapply(List_colfilter, longestlist)
```